# Путь содержит недопустимые знаки

Tags: c#, xml, исключения, io

в это строчке  `document.Load(filename: System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\doc"));`                 программа выдает ArgumentException "Путь содержит недопустимые знаки."   Файл в данном пути существует. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?
Котик_хочет_кушать, вы правы, это одно и то же, извиняюсь, за неопытностью не углядел в корень (:

Comment: файл без расширения\добавление расширения не решает проблему

Comment: Аргумент `filename` подразумевает собой **путь** до файла, а вы передали текстовое **содержимое** файла:

> `filename`

> Type: `System.String`

> URL for the file containing the XML document to load. The URL can be either a local file or an HTTP URL (a Web address).

Comment: filename не влияет на работоспособность. этот аргумент просто повышает читаемость кода. при его добавлении\удалении работа (и соответсвенно появление исключения) никак не изменяется (только что попробовал) поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: оу, я кажется понял где я был не прав, извиняюс, я просто использовал неподходящую для этого случаю перегрузку метода Load(). не подскажите как код, предоставленный в этом отрывке http://i.imgur.com/5QZbq.png преобразовать в работоспособное состояние? Заранее благодарен

Comment: @Егор 

- То, о чем говорите вы — это использование [named arguments,](http://codebetter.com/2011/01/11/c-in-depth-optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-2/) т.е `Foo(filename: bar)` вместо `Foo(bar)`. Это — синтаксический сахар, который не влияет на поведение программы.

- Я же имел ввиду, что то, что вы хотите сделать, делается с помощью `document.Load(@"E:\doc");`

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать
Простите, но мне кажется что вы тоже не правы, как был и не прав я. Я нашел решения проблемы: использование метода (XmlDocument.Load) не уместно в данном контексте. В случае с ReadAllText, который получает строку из файла, единтсвенный верным решением является использование метода (XmlDocument.LoadXml)

Comment: @Егор Вы действительно утверждаете, что `document.Load(@"E:\doc")` и `document.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(@"E:\doc"))` - это не одно и то же в вашем случае?

Comment: Ой... Как я люблю время сессий в ВУЗах)))

Answer (score 1):

расширение у файла отсутствует.

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

        // This text is added only once to the file.
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            string createText = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
        }

        // This text is always added, making the file longer over time
        // if it is not deleted.
        string appendText = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine;
        File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);

        // Open the file to read from.
        string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
        Console.WriteLine(readText);
    }
}
```

Comment: файл без расширения

Comment: попробуйте дописать файлу расширение и проверьте, если проблема исчезнет будем думать как решить.

Comment: я уже как только вы написали ваш ответ, дополнил коментарием вопрос, о том что такой способ не решает проблему. Вообще я очень сильно упростил вызов из своей программы этого файла, но проблема как была так и осталась.

Comment: if (!File.Exists(path))   поставьте проверку.
что она скажет.

есть подозрение что у Вас буква диска написана на русском языке.

Comment: Изначально был такой путь (System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\doc")
ваша догадка о букве неверна. Так же файл существует (проверка для входа в эту веть выполняетяс гораздо раньше)

Comment: кстати а симол **\** явно лишний если файл лежит в корне.

да и часть кода привести не помешает, да и по моему **GetCurrentDirectory** уже дает путь с заключительным слешем

Comment: Да, поэтому заключительный слэш добавляется в \doc и лишним не является. Код вынес специально в отдельный проект http://i.imgur.com/5QZbq.png

Answer (score 1):

Из комментариев:

Топикастер читал содержимое файла (`File.ReadAllText`), и отдавал его методу `XmlDocument.Load`.

Метод `Load` ожидает путь к файлу, а не его содержимое.

Нужно было или убрать вызов `File.ReadAllText`, или использовать метод `XmlDocument.LoadXml`.